# PLY yacc parser : how can I create a recursive rule for parsing matrices?

Tags: parsing, matrix, yacc, ply

I'm trying to parse matrices written this way : `[[1,2];[3,2];[3,4]]`

So, the matrix syntax is of the form: `[[A0,0, A0,1, ...]; [A1,0, A1,1, ...];...]`

The **semicolon** is used to separate the rows of a matrix, so it is not present in theassignment of a matrix that has only one row. On the other hand, the **comma** is usedto separate the columns of a matrix, which on the other hand will not be present in the assignment of a matrix that has only one column.

Now my question is : how can I parse a matrix with a variable size ? I guess with recursive rule in ply yacc, but how? Every attempt lead to a infinite recursion.

This is the error I get :

```
WARNING: Symbol 'primary' is unreachable
WARNING: Symbol 'expr' is unreachable
ERROR: Infinite recursion detected for symbol 'primary'
ERROR: Infinite recursion detected for symbol 'expr'
```

When I thry this kind of code:

```
def p_test(t):
'''primary : constant
           | LPAREN expr RPAREN'''
print('yo')
t[0] = 1


def p_expression_matrice(t):
'''expr : primary 
        | primary '+' primary'''
print('hey')
t[0] = 1
```

*(this i just a first attempt to understand how to write recurion in yacc, not even an answer to my real problem)*

**This is my lexer** :

```py
from global_variables import tokens
import ply.lex as lex

t_PLUS      = r'\+'
t_MINUS     = r'\-'
t_TIMES     = r'\*'
t_DIVIDE    = r'\/'
t_MODULO    = r'\%'
t_EQUALS    = r'\='
t_LPAREN    = r'\('
t_RPAREN    = r'\)'
t_LBRACK    = r'\['
t_RBRACK    = r'\]'
t_SEMICOLON = r'\;'
t_COMMA     = r'\,'
t_POWER     = r'\^'
t_QUESTION  = r'\?'
t_NAME      = r'[a-zA-Z]{2,}|[a-hj-zA-HJ-Z]'    # all words (only letters) except the word 'i' alone
t_COMMAND   = r'![\x00-\x7F]*'                  # all unicode characters after '!' 

def t_NUMBER(t):
    r'\d+(\.\d+)?'
    try:
        t.value = int(t.value)
    except:
        t.value = float(t.value)
    return t

def t_IMAGINE(t):
    r'i'
    t.value = 1j
    return t

t_ignore = " \t"

def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

lexer = lex.lex()
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a definition of `constant`.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "an array of variable size"? Do you mean "more than two dimensions"? If not, what aspect of variable size confuses you? IIRC, you have variable length expressions with recursive definition.

Comment: Hello again @rici ! By matrices of variables size, I mean that I should be able to parse this matrix : [[1,2];[3,2];[3,4]] AND also this matrix : [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]. My difficulty : I cannot match the first line of the matrix with this rule : 'LBRACK expression RBRACK' I need to specify 'LBRACK NUMBER COMMA NUMBER RBRACK' for example. But this work only with a 2 number line matrix. So I'm looking for a rule that will parse all numbers, no matter how much, between 2 brackets.

Comment: @rici I didn't really understannd that something simple as that : '''expression : expression PLUS expression''' is already kinda recursion in yacc grammar. I do now.

Comment: It *is* recursion. No 'kinda' about it.

Answer (score 0):

After multiple tries, I got this :

```py
    def p_test3(t):
        '''expression : expression SEMICOLON expression'''
        t[0] = []
        t[0].append(t[1])
        t[0].append(t[3])

    def p_test2(t):
        '''expression : LBRACK expression RBRACK'''
        t[0] = t[2]


    def p_test(t):
        '''expression : expression COMMA NUMBER'''
        t[0] = [] 
        try:
            for i in t[1]:
                t[0].append(i)
        except:
            t[0].append(t[1])
        t[0].append(t[3])
```

Which alllows me to parse this : `[[1,2,3,4,5];[5,4,3,2,1]]` to get this : `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]` stored in a array of array.
Next step, I will store many of these in a dict and I'ill keep going, thanks for the support @rici :)